# php echo fails if I echo "<"

Tags: php, html, select

I have a strange problem which I presume is to do with my setup (WAMP on Windows 10). I am a beginner and working on my first project (rewriting an old Access/VBA solution).

I want to create an HTML drop down list on the fly - mysqli_query works fine and I can echo the list I need and get an accurate row count. But when I try any echo statement which starts with a '<' the rest of the page doesn't run.

The < is fine anywhere else but at the beginning. What I need is to be able to put

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<option value ='".$row['schoolName']."'>".$row["schoolName"]."</option>";
}
```

This just displays a list of $row["schoolName"] biut no other text.

There may be some mistakes in that code but I have tested this with much shorter echo strings and they always fail if '<' is the first thing after echo. I don't get an error message - the code above just gives a correct list of $row['schoolName].

Any ideas?

Comment: You /are/ outputting to a `select` tag yes?

Comment: have you looked at you page source? because if you do get *some* output, it means it's not your code that fails...

Comment: maybe you're looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: And it is nothing to do with WAMPServer or its setup

Comment: Simply post the resulting html markup as you pick it from the browser. Add it to your question. Then we can tell you what the issue is.

Comment: What other text were you expecting? Can you confirm that the `<option>` tags exist INSIDE a select tag like so `<select><option></option><option></option></select>`

Comment: Any reply to these questions is better than no reply! People wont wait around for long

Comment: Thanks for all these - I wan't very clear. Ultimately I want to fill the Select part of my html but  I found this problem while just seeing if I could echo the required text before working it into the html. I am beginning to suspect from all you comments that unless I go straight to the creation of the Select I can't actually just echo the code to the screen. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select name="" id="input" class="form-control">
<?php
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<option value ='".$row['schoolName']."'>".$row["schoolName"]."  </option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions but still no luck. Just to repeat - anything that starts with echo '<   ' just fails - no error, no output. Doesn't matter what the context is for the echo. I am very puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the `<select>` tag before using an `<option>` tag.

```
<select name="" class="">
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<option value ='".$row['schoolName']."'>".$row["schoolName"]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```